# Изменить размер Bitmap при этом не потеряв картинку C#

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

Входные данные картинка (Bitmap) неизвестного размера, ширина, высота.

Выходные данные картинка (Bitmap) с заданой шириной и высотой.

```
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
```

В pictureBox1 картинка 720 на 960px

Comment: что значит не потеряв

Comment: Сложно найти и легко потерять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Bitmap b1 = new Bitmap(@"test.jpg");
Bitmap b2 = new Bitmap(b1, new Size(100, 200));
```